# Query a for a specific object type in a collection

Tags: linq

If you have two objects, ObjectA and ObjectB both inheriting from AbstractObject and a collection of AbstractObject. What would a linq statement look like where I select all objects in the collection of specific type. ex. something like:

```
var allBs = from b in collection where type == ObjectB select b;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
var allBs = collection.OfType<ObjectB>();
```

This gives you all elements where the type is *castable* to `ObjectB`.  If you want objects which are only of type of `ObjectB`:

```
var allBs = collection.Select(i => i.GetType() == typeof(ObjectB));
```

or, alternatively:

```
var allBs = from b in collection 
            where b.GetType() == typeof(ObjectB) 
            select b;
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectB> allBs = collection.OfType<ObjectB>();
```

Or:

```
IEnumerable<AbstractObject> allBy = from b in collection
                                    where b is ObjectB
                                    select b;
```

The second query retains the same enumerable type as the collection, the first implicitly casts to `IEnumerable<ObjectB>`.

You could use these alternatives to cast the second query to `IEnumerable<ObjectB>`.

```
IEnumerable<ObjectB> allBs = (from b in collection
                              where b is ObjectB
                              select b).Cast<ObjectB>();

IEnumerable<ObjectB> allBs = from b in collection
                             where b is ObjectB
                             select b as ObjectB;
```

Comment: @"Reed Copsey" - I think the OP is a bit ambiguous as to whether it is all objects of a type including derived types or excluding derived types. Given that the code `b is ObjectB` returns true even when `b` is derived from `ObjectB` I went with the "included" meaning. Is that the point you were making?